# Represent this Image django Model

Tags: python, django, model

[image]

I am trying to build a multichoice question app with Department -> subject -> questions relations but I am confused on how to get questions in relation to the given subjects  just like the image i have posted.

```
from django.db import models
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey
from django.template.defaultfilters import truncatewords_html


class Exam(models.Model):
    exam_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.exam_name

class Year(models.Model):
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("year",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.year

class Department(models.Model):
    department=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name=("department"))
    def __str__(self):
        return self.department

class Subject(models.Model):
    department  = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject     = models.CharField(max_length=36)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject

class Question(models.Model):
    exam_name   = models.ForeignKey(
        Exam,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    year        = models.ForeignKey(
        Year,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    department  = models.ForeignKey(
        Department,
        blank= True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    subject     = ChainedForeignKey(
        Subject,
        chained_field="department",
        chained_model_field="department",
        auto_choose = True,
        related_name='question',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        ) 
    question = models.TextField(blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} >>> {}'.format(self.question, self.subject.subject)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content  = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    answer   = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)`
```

The Image above is what i intend the question area to be like user can navigate each tab of subject and answer questions and or select questions according to the number in pagination.

Comment: Your question seems vague. Can you post the code in your models.py file and how you designed your models? Should a subject contain multiple questions? This is a foreign key relation... So pls show us your Subject model and your Question model and how you tried to connect them.. (and we can try to comment on that ;))

Comment: @mekanik i've added my attempt to create the model for the template

Comment: could you elaborate on the relation between subject and department? I don't know this ChainedForeignKey thing (I can guess about it ;)) - Maybe you could try to build first a simple app with only subject (without departments...). It would definitely help  to formulate a clearer question.

Comment: Each department has a set of related subject I'm using django-smart-select to handle department to subject relation and works fine. My problem is subjects to question now and how to add the answer form.